# SQL: union multiple single row results sets from the same query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that, when given a specific date, examines a large dataset (around 36m and growing) and returns an aggregate.  Everything is working as expected... However, my end goal is to be able to determine a yearly average of these values.  Perhaps my brain is running on empty, but I'm trying to do this dynamically where I don't have to run the query 365 times and then average.....

I need to find the yearly average of the 365 results, *per* @inst, *per* @program.

Any pointers in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Query:

```
USE HCODS
GO

DECLARE @user_date DATETIME
DECLARE @inst VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @program VARCHAR(4)
SELECT @user_date = '9/30/2016'
SELECT @inst = 'SAC'
SELECT @program = 'PSU';

WITH T AS (
    SELECT
         B.OFFENDERID
        ,Institution = I.ORGCOMMONID
        ,BedUse = B.BEDUSE
        ,BeginEffectiveDtTm = CAST(B.BEDASSIGNMENTDATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(B.BEDASSIGNMENTTIME AS DATETIME)
        ,EndEffectiveDtTm = CASE WHEN B.BEDASSIGNMENTSTATUS = 'U' THEN 
            (CAST(B.INMBEDSTATUSDATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(B.INMBEDSTATUSTIME AS DATETIME)) ELSE NULL END

    FROM ODS.BEDASSIGNMENT (NOLOCK) B

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT F.PARTYID, I.ORGCOMMONID
        FROM ODS.ORGANIZATIONPROF (NOLOCK) AS F
        INNER JOIN ODS.ORGANIZATIONPROF (NOLOCK) AS I ON F.ORGAREACODE = I.PARTYID
        ) AS I ON B.FACILITYWHEREBEDLOCATED = I.PARTYID

    WHERE B.BEDASSIGNMENTDATE BETWEEN '1/1/2016' AND '12/31/2016'
        AND B.BEDASSIGNMENTSTATUS IN ('U','M')
        )

SELECT CAST(@user_date AS DATE)
    ,T.INSTITUTION
    ,T.BEDUSE
    ,COUNT(*)

FROM T

WHERE
    ( 
        (
        T.BEGINEFFECTIVEDTTM <= DATEADD(second,-1,(@user_date+1))
        AND
        T.ENDEFFECTIVEDTTM >= @user_date
        )
    OR T.ENDEFFECTIVEDTTM IS NULL
    )
    AND T.INSTITUTION = @inst
    AND T.BedUse = @program

GROUP BY
     T.Institution
    ,T.BedUse
```

Result sets (each one obtained by a single running of the query)

```
Date       |Institution |BedUse |Count
-----------|------------|-------|-------
2016-09-30 |SAC         |PSU    |446
2016-10-01 |SAC         |PSU    |421
2016-10-02 |SAC         |PSU    |423

etc......
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example of a results set of an execution of this query, and an example of what you're looking to produce?

Comment: Show the query itself would be good, too.

Comment: Certainly!  just added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is hard to answer the question of your data without seeing it.  I can turn you onto a SQL concept of windowed functions.  This in essense is doing an inline grouping to aggregate data.  If I have a single set but want to fashion multiple statements over it to see different things, this statement is perfect.

So in an example I am in essence going from the 1st of January of 2015 to today(dynamic as this could be any day even after I post this).  I am then picking a random number of 1 to 100 to populate my row of data in my temporary set with.  I then can do my aggregate operations on that.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE ( Id INT IDENTITY, val INT, dt DATETIME)

DECLARE @Start DATETIME = '1-1-2015'

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WHILE @Start <= GETDATE()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 100, @Start)

        SELECT @Start = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @STart)
END

SELECT DISTINCT
    SUM(Val) OVER() AS TotalValues
,   COUNT(*) OVER() AS rowCounts
,   DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, Dt), 0) AS YearDate
,   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, Dt), 0)) AS DaysInYear
,   SUM(Val) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, Dt), 0)) AS ValsByYear
,   AVG(Val) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, Dt), 0)) AS AVGByYear
,   DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, Dt), 0) AS MonthDate
,   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, Dt), 0)) AS DaysInMonth
,   SUM(Val) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, Dt), 0)) AS ValsByMonth
,   AVG(Val) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(MOnth, 0, Dt), 0)) AS AVGByMonth
From @Data
```

Comment: No prob, when I first learned windowed functions with SQL it was like opening up a whole new world.